# Return dynamic CheckBoxList span ID on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a dynamic `CheckBoxList` that creates an HTML table. I've listed one row to keep it simple.

```
<table id="checkBoxList1" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><span someValue="neededValue"><input id="checkBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxList1$0" checked="checked" /><label for="checkBoxList1_0">TestTopic1</label></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also have an ASP button that will run javascript when clicked. I need the function to return the `"neededValue"`. Here is the ASP button and the javascript function:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Update Subscriptions" OnClientClick="return GetSelectedItem()"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedItem() {
    var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=checkBoxList1.ClientID%>");
    var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var spans = CHK.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked) {
            alert("Selected = " + spans[i]);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Right now it returns a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `spans[i]` with `checkbox[i].parentNode.getAttribute('someValue')`.

I recommend using jQuery. It simplifies your code a lot, for example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Update Subscriptions" />

$(function() {
    $('#<%=btnSubscribe.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
        $('#<%=checkBoxList1.ClientID%> input:checked').each(function() {
            alert('Selected = ' + $(this).closest('span').attr('someValue'));
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```